# htaccess redirect urls with parameters to specific directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, web

i want to redirect specific urls from

```
http://www.domain.com/com/page.asp?id=99
to
https://www.domain.com/de/directory/
```

and all urls from

```
http://www.domain.com/com/page.asp
to
https://www.domain.com/de/
```

ive tried some redirects but i cant get it done right.
Please help me!

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} id=5
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com/de/directory/? [R=301,L]

this works, but the biggest problem is all urls in the cms https://www.domain.com/cms are redirected too if they contain an id
```

Comment: Is `/com/` before `page.asp` a real directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=99$
RewriteRule ^page\.asp$ /de/directory/ [L,R]
RewriteRule ^page\.asp$ /de/ [L,R]
```